# Determine if other end closed (abruptly) the tcp connection

Tags: node.js

I've built a small, basic tcp server in nodejs to which external devices can connect over a tcp-socket.
From each connected device I only want to store one socket which is the active open connection to this device. If for some reason the connection gets closed by the device I want my server to know and do stuff (eg splice the socket from activeSocketList, notify in a room in socket.io etc etc)

Server, straight forward:

```
var server = net.createServer(function(c){
  // new connection is online            
     logToOversight(c.remoteAddress + ' > Connection Established');
     c.setKeepAlive(true);

  //  Do something with incoming data.
      c.on('data', function(buffer) {
        parseMessage(c, buffer);
      })

  //- Connection gets an end-event from us.
      c.on('end', function() {
          // server closes the connection
      })
}).listen(port);
```

I've looked at the events [close](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_event_close)  and end but they seem only to catch ending connections initiated by the server itself.

While I want to catch the abrupt end of connection from the devices side. E.g. I connect via netcat to the server for testing:

```
nc example.com 12345
```

And 'close' the connection via ctrl-z I want to catch that 'event' on the server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> And 'close' the connection via ctrl-z I want to catch that 'event' on the server side

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> in a Unix terminal *suspends* the process. It does not close any active TCP connections so your server still has a valid TCP connection to the client, even though that client will not be able to send or consume data until you resume it with `fg`. See for yourself with `netstat`, it'll still be there in the `ESTABLISHED` state.

Both a graceful close of a TCP connection with the exchange of `FIN` packets and an abrupt close indicated with an `RST` should both be indicated by the `close` event that you already know about.

The worst case is a yanking out of the network cable or equivalent such as an abrupt termination of the client's power supply. To detect this case you must implement heartbeats and timeouts between your server and its clients.